# Accepting String when format specified is character

Tags: c, string, char, scanf

I have the below code. I was thinking I should input only one character at a time. But even if I give a string like hello as input in one line, it accepts correctly. Why is this? Is it related to standard input buffer flushing issue?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <conio.h>


int main()
{
    char sourceString [100];
    int index=0;
    printf("Enter the characters one by one enter * to stop\n");
    do
    {
        scanf("%c",&sourceString[index]);
        index++;
    } while (sourceString[index-1]!='*');

    index=0;
    while (sourceString[index]!='*')
    {
        printf("%c",sourceString[index]);
        index++;
    }
    printf("\n");

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: "if I give a string like hello as input in one line, it accepts correctly" --> How is this different that what you expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you enter a *string* and press ENTER, the whole string goes into the input buffer `stdin`.

Next, as per the property of `%c` format specifier, as mentioned in the `C11` standard, chapter §7.21.6.2, *`fscanf()`*

> Matches a sequence of characters of exactly the number specified by the field
>   width (1 if no field width is present in the directive).

It will match (and scan and store) the first entry (`char`) in the buffer leaving the rest of the buffer content unchanged.

As you're running the `scanf()` in a loop, the next call will again go and read from the input buffer ( and continue as long as their is content pending in the `stdin` buffer).

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong here? It's accepting *one character at a time*, no matter how many characters there are and putting *one character at a time* into an array until a condition is met. This is just a (more complicated) way to input a string with an asterisk (`*`) acting like a null-terminator (`'\0'`).

By the way, you should check the bounds in your first loop. Add something like this or your program will crash with a segfault when the input string gets bigger than 100 characters.

```
do {
    // your code here
} while ((sourceString[index-1]!='*') && (index < 100));
```

Answer (score 0):

When using scanf you need to terminate the input with a whitespace character(e.g. \n). The scanf will finish reading input when you enter a newline. However since you have a loop it will keep reading input until you enter "*".